# Editing multiple resource file keys at once in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resourcebundle

I have a c# application and I use visual studio 2013 to develop it. In trying to support i18n, resource files were made for every language:

```
resources.en.resx
resources.fr.resx
resources.es.resx
resources.de.resx and so on...
```

I want to change a KEY (not the value) of all the resource files to something more descriptive, for example change "Header.Text" to "MainExceptionTitle.Text" Currently, I see no way to do this but to change it manually in every file, which is very tedious.

I looked into the [zeta resource editor](http://www.zeta-resource-editor.com/index.html) project, but it also only allows the editing of values and not keys.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `.resx` files are XML, you can do a simple find & replace on them.

Use Visual Studio's *[Replace in Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a40ywt0a(v=vs.120).aspx)* tool to do this across all `.resx` files, like so:

[image: Replace in Files dialog]

Answer (score 2):

I have used Zeta too - This is what works for me:

- Creating standalone projects in zeta, containing multiple languages
- Editing both keys and the local(national) values

What does not work is changing the naming convension, so that it compiles in visual studio.

The naming of ..resx result in standalon resource files, that dont compile in visual studio in an ASP.NET project - The .design files do not compile.

When changing filenames to the following convension _.resx, Zeta cannont manage the files any more, but visual studio compiles the corresponding .Design files.

... mutual exclution??

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your answer. How I read the first 3 lines is: "Zeta works for me and allows me to edit keys"

Comment: Oh... let me clarify.
Zeta aligns keys and national variations, aligned in a single row. Example "MY_SPECIAL_KEY" => Danisk "Min special Nøgle", and in English => "My special key".

Additional It is also possible to change the key Identity from MY_SPECIAL_KEY to e.g. MY_COMMON_KEY.

Anyways, I learned that Zeta was open source. Therefore I cloned the program on github, and modified it, and how it follows the convension 
`<projectname>_<national tag>.resx`
The project is available from: [github](https://github.com/theodorjohannesen/ZetaResourceEditor)

Answer (score 1):

If you have Resharper installed, there is a very simple and safe way:

1. Open the matching designer file (this is a C# file generated from the resx, called `<ResxFileName>.Designer.cs`).
2. Navigate to the resource property in question. You will find a static property here for every key defined in the resx file.
3. Use the Resharper rename command (Ctrl-R, Ctrl-R on my machine).

Resharper opens the "Rename Resource" dialog, which updates all resource keys correctly.